# How lazy sequence run in this code

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

Code is here:

```
(def fib-seq (lazy-cat [0 1]  (map + (rest fib-seq) fib-seq )))
```

As I could understand that the `fib-seq` is a lazy sequence generator that generate a serial of fibonacci number.
By take a look at `(take 5 fib-seq)` I will get fibonacci number as below:
`(0 1 1 2 3)`

But I can not figure out how the lazy sequence is generated when need, so I add some side effect on it.

```
(def fib-seq (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + 
    (do (println "R") (rest fib-seq)) 
    (do (println "B") fib-seq))))
```

By adding the `println` I expect it to print out `R` and `B` whenever  lazy sequence try to generate new entry when it needed, but unfortunately this turn out to be like this.

```
user=> (take 5 fib-seq) ; this is the first time I take 5 elements
(0 R
B
1 1 2 3)
```

The output above look already weird as it do not print R and B element by element, but let's take a look at next step.

After take elements for the first time:

```
user=> (take 20 fib-seq)
(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987 1597 2584 4181)
```

I will never receive the `R` and `B` anymore, which makes me puzzle as it conflicted with my comprehension to lazy sequence's generate.

Could any explain it step by step to me?
BTW, is there any possibility to have a `debug` utility to debug it `step by step` just like `Java` and `C`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, step by step:

1. Here's the source code for `lazy-cat` ([link](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/028af0e0b271aa558ea44780e5d951f4932c7842/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4244)):

   ```clj
   (defmacro lazy-cat
     "Expands to code which yields a lazy sequence of the concatenation
     of the supplied colls.  Each coll expr is not evaluated until it is
     needed. 

     (lazy-cat xs ys zs) === (concat (lazy-seq xs) (lazy-seq ys) (lazy-seq zs))"
     {:added "1.0"}
     [& colls]
     `(concat ~@(map #(list `lazy-seq %) colls)))
   ```

   So your code:

   ```clj
   (def fib-seq (lazy-cat [0 1] (map + 
       (do (println "R") (rest fib-seq)) 
       (do (println "B") fib-seq))))
   ```

   Expands to this:

   ```clj
   (def fib-seq (concat (lazy-seq [0 1])
                        (lazy-seq (map +
                                       (do (println "R") (rest fib-seq)) 
                                       (do (println "B") fib-seq)))))
   ```

   `concat` itself returns a lazy sequence which means that the body of the `concat` form is not evaluated until you traverse `fib-seq`.
2. When you traverse `fib-seq` for the first time (when you take the first `5` elements), the body of the `concat` form is first evaluated:

   ```clj
   (concat (lazy-seq [0 1])
           (lazy-seq (map +
                          (do (println "R") (rest fib-seq))
                          (do (println "B") fib-seq))))
   ```

   The first two elements of the lazy sequence returned by `concat` are taken from `(lazy-seq [0 1])`, which in turn takes them from `[0 1]` ; after this point, `[0 1]` is exhausted so so is `(lazy-seq [0 1])` and the next elements of the `concat` sequence are taken from the `(lazy-seq (map ...))` subsequence.

   Here the `do` special forms get evaluated, both of them, and you see `R` and `B` printed. The semantics of `do` is to evaluate all the forms within it, then to return the result of the last one.

   So `(do (println "R") (rest fib-seq)` prints `R`, then returns the result of `(rest fib-seq)`, and `(do (println "B") fib-seq))` prints `B`, then returns `fib-seq`.

   `(map ...)` returns a lazy sequence ; when the traversal reaches `fib-seq`'s 3rd element, the first element of the `map` sequence is evaluated ; it is the sum of the first element of `fib-seq` (i.e. `0`) and of the first of `(rest fib-seq)` i.e. the second of `fib-seq` (i.e. `1`). Both are already evaluated at this point, so we don't end up with an infinite recursion.

   For the next elements, the laziness of `map` prevents an infinite recursion to occur, and the magic occurs.
3. On your second traversal of `fib-seq` (i.e. `(take 20 fib-seq)`), the first few elements of it have already been evaluated, so the `do` special forms are not re-evaluated and the traversal continues without side effects.

---

To have `R` and `B` printed whenever new elements are pulled from `(rest fib-seq)` and `fib-seq`, you'd have to do this:

```clj
(def fib-seq
  (lazy-cat [0 1]
            (map + 
                 (map #(do (println "R") %) (rest fib-seq)) 
                 (map #(do (println "B") %) fib-seq)))))
```

Comment: thanks for your patient answer, it is very nice to have such a good reply. Actually I do know some of clojure's execution logic, but it puzzled me when referring to laziness.

Comment: Actually I use the code you provide to have a test, it seems rather weird as  `(nth fib-seq 0);0`  `(nth fib-seq 1); 1`  `(nth fib-seq 2); RBB1`  `(nth fib-seq 3); R2`  `(nth fib-seq 4); RB3`   `(nth fib-seq 5); RB5`

Comment: As you can see that I sequentially get the item, the first 2 item looks fine and the last two also good, but the `No.2` and `No.3` item looks uncomfortable as it print `RBB` and `R` respectively, I can not figure this out, it is comprehensible that last two item is generated by adding `(rest fib-seq))` and  `fib-seq` together, but what about the two items in middle?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @omiel provide many useful information, but still did not touch the most sensitive point, after thinking a while, I figure out what happened in the generation of lazy sequence.
May `clojure master` in SO please correct me if I am actually wrong.

What I mean step by step actually foci on the generation of lazy-sequence item one by one, I already know some of the logic of clojure language.

As we know the `fib-seq` is defined as a `lazy-seq` and its first two items is 0 and 1, the rest of its items still left unevaluated, which is the most interesting feature of clojure.
While it is rather easy to understand that accessing the first two item just means to touch those two things, and they are in memory or cached, thus they could be directly return and print out.

As `fib-seq` do not have third item for now, it need to generate it when thread need to accessing the 3rd item, here is where my assumption start:

Since `(map + (rest fib-seq) fib-seq )` is a `lazy-seq` itself, it contain no item in it currently and waiting for calling `more` command on it.
Here calling the 3rd item of `fib-seq` means calling the first item of lazy sequence `(map...)`, hence it need to generate and real execute the code.
By simply replace variable name with list, the code of map seems like this:

```
(map + (rest [0 1 ..]) [0 1 ..] ); the '..' means it is a lazy sequence
```

then this code is become below after `rest` executed:

```
(map + [1 ..]  [0 1 ..] )
        ^       ^
        | ----- |
            |
            +
            1
```

As `map` generate lazy sequence, it is instructed to generate the first item of it, so by `map` these two lists, we got an item `1=(+ 1 0)` which is the result of both the first item of these two lists add together.

Then the `map` stop generate item as it have no instruction to do so.  Now after generate the new item `1` and concatenate it with `[0 1]`, our `fib-seq` now look like this:

```
[0 1 1 ..]
```

Pretty good. Now let's touch the 4th item of `fib-seq` by `(nth fib-seq 4)`.
fib-seq find it contain no item with index `4`, but it found the third is cached so it will generate the `4th` item from `3rd` one.

Now thread move to `(map ...)` function and instruct map to hand out the second item of it.
map found it did not have No.2 item so it have to generate it.  and replace  `fib-seq` with real lazy seq:

```
(map + (rest [0 1 1..]) [0 1 1..] )
```

Then of course `rest` get the rest of seq:

```
(map + [1 1..] [0 1 1..] )
```

Here the most tricky thing happened I think.
`Map` add both the second rather than the first item of these lists:

```
(map + [1 1..] [0 1 1..] )
          ^       ^
          | ----- |
              |
              +
              2
```

So the map could return `2` as its 2nd item so as to complete the instruction.

The `lazy-seq` follow the same strategy in the follow item while instructed, and cache every generated item in memory for faster accessibility.

For this `Fibonacci number generator`, it just shift two list and add them one by one and recursively to generate required Fibonacci number like below:

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 ..   
1 1 2 3 5 ..
```

Which of course is a very deft way to generate `Fibo`.

## summary

To sum up, from human's view, lazy seq will generate item always from its last status/position rather than starting from its initial state.

Please correct me if I am wrong, I am a newbie in `clojure` and I am eagerly to learn it well.

#### BTW

I want to write a `netbeans language plugin` for `clojure` integrate with `leiningen` as I think `lighttable` is useless, anyone have any suggestion?